# How to set custom EDID manually?

Tags: x11, nvidia, wayland, edid, kms

My monitor connects to the videocard through the DVI->VGA adapter, and EDID is not transmitted. If you use Xserver, then this problem is solved by adding previosly saved EDID in xorg.conf:

```
Option         "CustomEDID" "DVI-I-0:/etc/X11/edid.bin"
Option         "IgnoreEDID" "false"
Option         "UseEDID" "true"
```

But what if you want to use some environment with Wayland? I tried the method from this [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes_and_EDID), but for some reason it did not work at all.

Comment: If nvidia is relevant, can you please say what driver you are using - noveau, or the closed-source driver?

Comment: im using closed-source driver, currently 381.22 version

Comment: It seems likely the drm_kms_helper options don't work given "The proprietary NVIDIA driver (since 364.12) also implements kernel mode-setting, _but it does not use the built-in kernel implementation_."